# Is there a way to store a variable as numeric in R but show as a date9 format?

Tags: r

```
as<-as.Date(today())

as_numeric<-as.numeric(as)
```

shows 18505 but unable to create a date9. format for it

Comment: Hi! Please, can you specify what is the `date9` format for whom is not familiar with it (like me)?

Comment: Date9 format is displaying date as day in numeric then month as 3 letter in capital and 4 digits in year as in "03SEP2020"

Comment: Just format it when you need to show it. Where exactly are you displaying the value where you need it formatted. Perhaps you can define your own class with a custom print method.

Comment: There is a list of variables that holds date values, for each date value there needs to be 2 variable, one that holds a numeric value which will be used for calculations and other is a character value. For instance, if the value to be stored is "03SEP2020" then it will be stored as DATEI as number and DATEC as character. Internally DATEI should be as a number but displayed value should be a date9 format as in 03SEP2020. Its easy to do in SAS but in R  findiing it bit difficult

Comment: Regarding "_holds a numeric value which will be used for calculations_" - you _can_ do basic calculations and logical comparisons on objects of class `Date`. See **Details** in `?Date`; `methods(class = "Date")`; `?Ops.Date`. To _display_ a date in a different format, for e.g. a report, use `format`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `toupper` + `format` + `as.Date` like below

```
> toupper(format(as.Date(as_numeric,origin = "1970-01-01"),format = "%d%b%Y"))
[1] "03SEP2020"
```

Comment: This is working fine to store the value as "03Sep2020" but the class of the variable is character. I wish to store the character as numeric but value displayed should be "03Sep2020"

Comment: @NavjotBajwa Did you use any package? In base R, I have no clue for your case